# Accessing Defined Javascript Function in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to access few functions from woocommerce js files in my wordpress plugin.

File location : woocommerce/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-order.js

File URL : https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-order.js

I have also included the file in using default wp functions and here is my javascript code

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    jQuery('#customer_user').on('change', function () {
        var user_id = $('#customer_user').val();
        var post_ID = $('#post_ID').val();
        $.wc_meta_boxes_order_items.reload_items();
        if (user_id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'rbp_admin_order_register',
                    userID: user_id,
                    orderID: post_ID
                },
                method: 'post',
            }).done(function () {
                //rbp_admin_order_metabox_unblock();
            })
        } else {
            //rbp_admin_order_metabox_unblock();
        }
    });
});
```

And i am getting **TypeError: $.wc_meta_boxes_order_items is undefined**

Comment: `wc_meta_boxes_order_items` is private variable... you don't have access to it outside its `jQuery(function ($) {` scope...

Comment: @Reigel is there no other way ??

Comment: if you mean accessing that variable, then yes... there's no way... that's how private variable works...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if someone still needs the above, but I did. After looking at the file mentioned above:

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-order.js

I found a way to to this without hacking it together, there are two registered event listeners which give the option to reload items or trigger after the items are reloaded.

```
    $( '#woocommerce-order-items' )
......
      // Reload items
        .on( 'wc_order_items_reload', this.reload_items )
        .on( 'wc_order_items_reloaded', this.reloaded_items )
```

So reloading the items can be done by simply calling the following method from within your code:

```
$( '#woocommerce-order-items' ).trigger('wc_order_items_reloaded');
```